# How to install a Brother dcp-135c printer?

Tags: printing, brother

Recently moved over onto Ubuntu. First time for anything like this for me as I'm coming from Windows but I'm here and ready to learn. The only problems Ive experienced so are saving in Libre office doc as a word doc file and then losing the formatting upon receival via email. However the more pressing issue is getting my old Brother DCP 135 c to work. Ive scanned a few help blogs and have found them frankly quite frightening.

Would it be possible for someone to write u a step by step guide (including explanations of terminology)

For those of us new to this magic world?

Comment: Will did it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/brother-scanner-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed)

Answer (score 4):

I have also a Brother printer (DCP-series) and it only started working after i installed  the Brother drivers. Have you tried that? If not, here's what it takes:

- [Here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-135C) you can find the driver for your printer (download the 2 .deb files).
- Open a terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`)
- If you are using a 64bit system, you have to install `ia32-libs`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
  ```

After that just double click in each of the .deb files you downloaded and install it using Software Center. This should make your printer work (if not try restarting the system). Also, you can find a more complete guide [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html#printcap1).

Answer (score 3):

Type "brother" in the search box in the Ubuntu Software center.
Install both drivers that you find there.

Then open the terminal and type (as in Salem's answer):

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

In my case the DCP-135 printer now works. However, the scanner facility does not currently work. I am still trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To put the scanner to work follow the instrutions on this post: [Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/brother-scanner-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed).
Samy's answer made my scanner work finally after months of investigation and failed trying.

Comment: Instead of writing an answer that point to the other post you should flag this question as a duplicate.