# Brother DCP-7070DW scanner not working after 16.04 update from 14.04

Tags: drivers, brother

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (upgraded from 14.04) and have installed a Brother DCP-7070DW multifunctional. I have installed all drivers already in 14.04 but did not get the scanner function  working on this install. I did get it working on an earlier Ubuntu install, also 14.04. I would like to fix this now but unsure how. I tried the solution in [Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/not-working-brother-scanner-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed/895848) unsuccessfully.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brscan-skey                                     0.2.4-1                                       amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan3                                         0.2.11-4                                      amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  brscan4                                         0.4.4-1                                       amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  cupswrapperdcp7070dw:i386                       2.0.4-2                                       i386         Brother DCP7070DW CUPS wrapper driver
ii  dcp7070dwlpr:i386                               2.1.0-1                                       i386         Brother DCP-7070DW LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                          3-5~ubuntu1                                   amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                           1.4-1                                         amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

The scanner is installed but probably configured incorrectly.

```
$  scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus3;dev2' is a Brother DCP-7070DW USB scanner
```

I installed gscan2pdf but when I run it I get:

```
*Error opening device: opening device 'brother4:bus3;dev2': Invalid argument
```

Simple scan sees the scanner but says: `Unable to connect to scanner`.

What can I do to tackle this issue?