# How to detect a Brother scanner connected via USB

Tags: scanner, brother, sane

I have a Brother all-in-one system (MFC-J4420DW). I installed its drivers and I can print from Ubuntu 16.04. But, when I try to scan (using simple-scan), the scanner is not detected.

I ran Brother's diagnostic utility:

```
sudo brsaneconfig4 -d
```

and got, among other messages:

```
# No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
# you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
# the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.
```

I did not understand this message. I looked at man sane-usb but saw instructions that are probably outdated (e.g. that libusb should be at least version 0.1.6. I have 2:1.0.20-1).

How can I help Ubuntu detect my USB scanner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was so silly... after hours of frustration, I just unplugged the USB cable and re-connected it. Then, I ran brsaneconfig4 -d again and got:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x033d [MFC-J4420DW]) at  libusb:001:013
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

Now I can print with simple-scan!

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me some time. This was exactly what I had to do with my Brother DS 640. It might be important to not use sudo (which I did). Have a great day! Edit: I used brsaneconfig5 -d which worked.