# Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 18.04 though driver installed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, brother

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and a brother DCP-375CW, a printer and scanner all in one. I downloaded the drivers and used the Driver Install Tool by brother.

This is the result: the system says the drivers are installed. The printer is actually working. But Simple Scan claims that the drivers are still missing.

I used the method to install the scanner like in 16.04 (see here [Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/brother-scanner-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed))

I ran the Brother Driver Install Script and made the necessary rights changes in

`/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane1.rules`

This does not seem to work in 18.04 anymore.

Maybe the Installer Script installs the Drivers in the wrong folder for 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

With (K)ubuntu 18.04
I ran the "Brother Install Tool" 09/13/2018 (2.2.1-1)
Skanlite launched but did not recognize any suitable device.
I then checked whether usr/lib64 content was copied to usr/lib ( or vice-versa)
but /usr/lib/sane was nowhere to be found ...

"mkdir /usr/lib/sane" command is required if the folder does not exist.
then copy from "/usr/lib64/sane/
"libsane-brother3.so"
"libsane-brother3.so.1"
"sane/libsane-brother3.so.7"
into "/usr/lib/sane"
 Skanlite runs fine as root or user now ...

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I tried everything on the web to solve this problem.  I HAD the MFC-7840W scanner working yesterday, but then cleaned up packages and couldn't get Simple Scan or Xsane to recognize the scanner.  Did symbolic links, copied the files, edited the rules, etc. Nothing worked.

Finally, I contacted Brother who sent me an infuriating email that read: Make sure you installed the drivers using these steps. Answer Link: [Install drivers (deb or rpm) using the Driver Install Tool - Linux](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/52188/track/AvNYogp3Dv8S~UngGsUe~yL3E3Mq5C75Mv~Z~zj~PP8Q)
 If you are still unable to scan please follow these steps. Answer Link: [Unable to scan - Linux](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/166572/track/AvNYogp3Dv8S~UngGsUe~yL3E3Mq5C75Mv~Z~zj~PP8Q)

Oh, Brother, I thought (pun intended).  I had already reinstalled the scanner driver several times.  But, since I had essentially given up, I thought I would try it before I wrote back and started a long back and forth support process.  I downloaded the complete driver installation package (including printer, etc.) and followed their instructions.

It worked, immediately.  If you have this problem, give it a try.

Comment: Their installer script has gotten better over time so its good to retry using the latest one (2.2.2-1 as of writing this). There's an issue though where the scanner expects some 32-bit drivers and the OS these days are only 64-bit, so you need to install the 'libusb' and "libnsl" libraries, and then rerun the install script after doing so. For Fedora 32/33 its "sudo dnf install libusb" and "sudo dnf install libnsl". I'd post full instructions but I don't have the rep points to be able to. Email me at my name with a dot between first/last and the usual gmail format after the @ for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install lib32stdc++6, if the tool didn't do that.
On my last borther scanner I had to do the follwing (note that your files may be different)

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libbrscandec3.so* /usr/lib
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/sane
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother3.so* /usr/lib/sane
```

Since 16.04 the directories changed, therefore the links. Also try to start scanning with sudo. If it works with sudo, you need to add "lp" to the user.
It could be that the target is not /
usr/lib, but /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu