# Scan button on Brother DCP-L2550DW does not work "No PC found"

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, brother

Ubuntu 18.04

Using this over local wifi network.

When I try to scan using the physical button, it prompts "scan to pc" press OK, then choose "file", then it says "no pc found"

I've installed drivers from the brother site and everything else works. I can scan to file using the Simple Scan software with Ubuntu and it works fine.

I installed the driver for the physical scan button mentioned here https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=dcpl2550dw_us&os=128 "Scan-key-tool 64bit (deb package)" and followed the instructions and installed it, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Run the Simple Scan app and scan from there instead. I had to make a few changes to make it work:

1) For Simple Scan to find the scanner I did this:

Find your printer IP address, and:

$sudo brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=DCPL2550DW ip=192.123.4.5

this changes this file:
$ more /etc/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg

2) I copied libraries /usr/lib64/ to /usr/lib/ but I'm not sure that is necessary.

3) If Simple Scan crashes while scanning like
"simples-scan crashed with SIGSEGV in make_cache_block()"
It was because Simple Scan was set to Photo, set it to Text, because it is a black and white device and there is no colour map for it.

Follow Related question and debugging ideas ref:

[Brother scanner not working in Ubuntu 16.04 though driver installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791556/brother-scanner-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-though-driver-installed#830230)

Comment: yes this is the workaround I currently have. But I'd like to get full funtionality out of this printer since the [openprinting](https://openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-DCP-L2550DW) site shows that it runs perfectly. Which is why I bought this printer in the first place.